# How to convert seconds to HH:MM:SS format without failing if hour more than 24

Tags: python, arrays, string, datetime, time

I need to convert `seconds` to `HH:MM:SS` format without failing if hour greater than `24hrs`.

Such as `04:32:18` or `26:23:37`

Here's what I tried:

```
import time

cd = time.time()

while True:
    # Count seconds
    te = int(time.time()-cd, 0)

    # Print the secs
    print('Time elapsed:', te, 'secs')
    time.sleep(1)
```

This code prints this result:

```
Time elapsed 1.0 secs
Time elapsed 2.0 secs
...
```

But I want this result:

```
Time elapsed 00:00:01 secs
Time elapsed 00:00:02 secs
...
```

And if the hour greater than ***24***, the program must run and print something like:

```
Time elapsed: 28:34:35
Time elapsed: 28:34:36
...
```

Hope you help.

Comment: Use a `datetime.Duration` and add 24x the days to the value to print?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can easily decompose your seconds in h, m, s with [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)

```py
def to_hms(s):
    m, s = divmod(s, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    return '{}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}'.format(h, m, s)
```

```
>>> to_hms(90127)
'25:02:07'
```

Comment: You should use `'{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}'` to get `00:00:01` as OP desires